# Section processing Failed Canonical bloc unknown

Tags: go-ethereum

i am running a light node for bsc and after a while i started getting this error :

```
 ERROR[06-18|00:56:15.755] Section processing failed                type=bloombits error="canonical block #8027496 unknown"
```

the node works perfectly but it uses too much CPU. and i think this error is the origin of the CPU usage spike.

is there any way of fixing this without having to reset the chain data? I tried opening the freezer, a fix I found when searching but that didn't work.